# How do I include a "resources" directory alongside (not in with) my built JAR/classes in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using Maven in IntelliJ and I want to include a 'resources' directory in my build output alongside the JAR and/or in whatever directory IntelliJ uses as the cwd when running my project. I don't want these files in the JAR/Classpath, just alongside the final built project.

The idea is that then, my project can refer to files named things in `src/ext-resources/foo.txt` as `resources/foo.txt`.

I'm currently using the following instruction in pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/resources</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/ext-resources</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However, this doesn't appear to actually make it accessible, and doesn't seem to be copying these files at all. At one point, my config resulted in the *subdirectories* of `src/ext-resources` being copied into `target/classes` for some reason, but they aren't being copied into `target/resources` no matter what.

How do I make maven copy this folder into my final output directory?

Comment: You want to treat some other folder as `resources` folder for your Jar?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov no, I don't need a resources folder to be packed into my Jar, I only need this directory to go alongside.

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/4018394/2000323